# Push method converts an array into a number in the component state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, lifecycle

I have an array of numbers stored in the state of my component and I'm triying to push another number using `setState` inside a timer in the `componentDidMount` method to see how it changes in the screen. But when timer finishes, the existing array gets replace by the number I passed as paramether in the push method instead of append it in the array.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array : [1,2,3,4,5]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        setTimeout(()=>this.setState(prevState=>({
            array: prevState.array.push(6),
        })), 5000)
    }

    render(){
        const newArray = this.state.array;
        return(
            <div>{newArray}</div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

I could make it work using spread operator instead of push, but now I wonder why it doesn't work with push as well.

Answer (score 4):

`Array.prototype.push` returns the length of the array after pushing an item which is why you get an unexpected result, you should use `Array.prototype.concat` instead which retuns a new array upon addition of the element

```
  setTimeout(()=>this.setState(prevState=>({
        array: prevState.array.concat(6),
  })), 5000)
```

Comment: you can also concat non-array values. `prevState.array.concat(6)` returns the same result, without the additional Array to wrap the `6`. You might want to check out [Symbol.isConcatSpreadable](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable)